# iOS React Native app using 67 dependencies too large

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing a complex app using React Native, and once installed on the iPhone, using Xcode, the size is too large, around 670 Mb I can see from settings.

My source folder, which contains the assets folder and all code for components and screens, has a size of 10.5 Mb. In the package.json I have 67 libraries installed for a total of 397 Mb of node_modules folder.

What's wrong with my configuration, how can I reduce the size of the app?

React Native 0.70.2

Thank you.

Comment: Is this during generating release build?

Comment: No, when I have installed the app on my iphone just to test it, and when you go to iPhone Storage you can see the size of the app.

Comment: Do you check the 'Rebuild from/with bitcode' while generating build? If so, uncheck & try again.